# Given an arc length and an angle, how do I get a sphere coordinate?

Tags: spherical-geometry, spherical-coordinates

Assuming I start at the top of a sphere and am given the radius of the sphere, an angle to turn, and a distance to walk along the sphere, how could I find my destination in the sphere coordinate system (r, θ, φ), where r is the radius, θ is the polar angle, and φ is the azimuthal angle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know $r$.  $\phi$ is the angle you are told to turn.  If you are told to walk a distance $d$, $\theta$ is simply $d/r$.  (I am working in angle units of radians here.)

Comment: and $\phi$ is undefined without further information.